# Keep a variable's value unchanging in Java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is my simple script:

```
public void cast(Player caster) {
    Location loc = caster.getTargetBlock(null, 512).getLocation();

    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                caster.sendMessage("" + loc);
                Block ice = caster.getWorld().getBlockAt(loc.add(a, b, c));
                ice.setTypeId(79);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so `loc` remains static and unchanging.  It has been changing throughout the for loop and I wish to prevent this.

Comment: You mean that when you call `loc.add(a, b, c)`, it should have no effect? What's wrong with just eliminating that call from the loop?

Comment: So you're sure that `loc` is changing?  What specifically is changing about it - the x, y, z coordinates?

Comment: @Ted Hopp if i remove the call add for loc it wont shift the coordinates from the reliative position using abc as the for loops, should be making a cube but its not...

Comment: This is confusing. You don't want `loc` to change, but you need it to change. Perhaps you just want to clone `loc` at the start of the method.

Comment: One reason that methods that change in place should return `void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer:

```
public void cast(Player caster){
    Location loc = caster.getTargetBlock(null, 512).getLocation();
    for (int c = -3; c < 3; c++)
        for (int b = -1; b < 5; b++)
            for (int a = -3; a < 3; a++) {
                Block ice = caster.getWorld().getBlockAt(loc.add(a, b, c));
                ice.setTypeId(79);
                loc = loc.subtract(a, b, c);
            }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as solved so people know to not keep trying. :)

Comment: I can't it says I have to wait 2 Days

Answer (score 0):

Loc most likely has an internal state that is incrementing and not resetting every time

```
public void cast(Player caster){
Location loc = caster.getTargetBlock(null, 512).getLocation();

int initalC = 0;
int initalB = 0;
int initalA = 0;
Location staticLoc;
for (int c = initalC; c < 2; c++)
{
    for (int b = initalB; b < 2; b++)
    {
        for (int a = initalA; a < 1; a++)
        {
            if (a == initalA && b == initalB && c == initalC) {
                 staticLoc = caster.getTargetBlock(null, 512).getLocation().add(a, b, c);
            }

            loc = staticLoc;
            caster.sendMessage("" + loc);
            Block ice = caster.getWorld().getBlockAt(staticLoc.add(a, b, c));
            ice.setTypeId(79);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No, a location is a different type of variable than an int

Comment: My apologies.  Edited to correct staticLoc type

Comment: And you didn't initialize staticLoc, I'm getting errors...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has already been answered, but I wish to present a more efficient method. Adding and subtracting from a Location is quite inefficient, especially when doing this in nested loops.

The Location object has a `clone()` method which returns an identical Location but which is *not* a reference to the original location. So really, all you need to do is:

```
public void cast(Player caster) {
    Location loc = caster.getTargetBlock(null, 512).getLocation();

    for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                caster.sendMessage("" + loc);
                caster.getWorld().getBlockAt(loc.clone().add(a, b, c)).setTypeId(79);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

If performance is an issue, I would even consider caching getWorld() in a local variable outside the for loops.